# Bulk rename files ascending in number

Tags: file, for-loop, rename, archlinux

I have a file called **5000.swf** and in another folder a bunch of .swf files with random names. Now i want to rename every file in the folder with the random names (for example word.swf to 5001.swf otherword.swf to 5002.swf and so on. Is this possible with a .sh script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using BASH:

```
#!/bin/sh

counter="$(basename /path/to/file/5000.swf ".swf")"

for i in /path/to/random/files/*.swf; do

   ((counter++))

   mv "$i" "$counter.swf";
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it when i am back from work - but it looks like it would work